# Entity Framework, Prevent duplicate records, simultaneous connections

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, duplicates

If i use entity framework as the backend for a MVC Web API one controller might look something like this (quick mockup):

```
   public class PersonController : ApiController
   {
        [HttpPost]
        public void AddPerson(Person val)
        {
            DbContext context = new DbContext();
            if(!context.Persons.Any(x=>x.Email == val.Email))
            {
                context.Persons.Add(val)
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        } 
   }
```

The problem being that if this operation was called 50, 100 times every few seconds (probably not a good example) there is a high possibility that multiple entries could be added with the same email address.

If the `val` parameter was a list of `Person` you could check the `changetracker` to see if someone had been added with the email address before you `SaveChanges()` but this doesn't work when you have lots of calls from different sources.

You cannot have a static `DBContext` either as it will throw an exception saying its busy.

One idea i did think of was the same setup but having a static method which returns a instance (the same instance) of a `dbcontext` but with a `lock()` on it creating a kind of like queue but this could impact performance an isn't a great idea.

How do you get around this?

The example is not relevant to what I'm doing but just something simple to explain the scenario. It doesn't have to be specific too i guess.

Thanks

Steve

Comment: What makes a new person unique? Are multiple persons with the same email address allowed? If no, then a unique constraint for the email property would certainly help. You should also consider why this operation gets called so often with duplicate information.

Comment: I don't just need to prevent the dupliction, i may need to pull and existing link which could of been created 0.00001ms before and link it to a new record. This example was clearly not the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need the DB to be updated real time, you might as well queue each request, and just have a single worker that would process the queued requests.

Comment: This was my only option but want to avoid something like this as it could slow it down.

Comment: Just avoid the lock to avoid paying for its overhead cost, if you can't afford to give up parallelism you can setup the "main" worker to dequeue a group of messages and have the latter filter out duplicates, then have delegates for each unique message. This setup would also remove the burden to your web service since the burden of processing would be passed to the worker.

Answer (score 2):

put a unique constraint index on the email table?
or
change your SQL Transaction Isolation level to Serializable?
or 
lock a static object so 1 method can go through that method at a time?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I don't know who or what the consumer is of this service. But why would the same user be added multiple times per second?
Multiple Addings of a Person with the same email address should indicate the same person, but other properties may differ. The question is then which do you want to "win", the first or the last?

A simple and effective way is to set a unique constraint on the Email property in the database and handle the exception in a suitable way.

Comment: It's actually for a data import, which would have 5-20 worker roles/threads doing the same operations from multiple sources all into the same database.